# Input data for Amazon Sagemaker Python SDK

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, amazon-sagemaker, dataformat

Hallo can someone tell me in what format my input data has to be. Now I have it in csv format with the first column being the target variable but I always get a Algorithm Error which I think is due to wrong input data format.

```
trainpath = sess.upload_data(
    path='revenue_train.csv', bucket=bucket,
    key_prefix='production')

testpath = sess.upload_data(
    path='revenue_test.csv', bucket=bucket,
    key_prefix='production')
```

```
# launch training job, with asynchronous call
sklearn_estimator.fit({'train':trainpath, 'test': testpath}, wait=False)
```

Comment: could you provide the full text of the algorithm error? and check in CloudWatch logs if they say something more detailed?

Answer (score 1):

when you use a custom Docker or framework estimator (like you do) you can use any file format (csv, pdf, mp4, whatever you have in S3). The Sklearn container and estimator are agnostic of the file format ; it is the role of your user-provided Python code in the estimator to know how to read those files.